# std::thread constructor ?specialization?. g++ vs clang++

Tags: c++, templates, g++, clang++, specialization

I need to specialize std::thread templated constructor.

The following code compiles well with g++ while fails during compilation with clang++ (6.0).

```
#include <thread>

class MyThread
{
  public:
    void start()
    {
      run();
    }

    virtual void run(void) {};
};


namespace std
{
  template<>
  thread::thread<MyThread*>(MyThread*&&)
  {
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::thread myThread(new MyThread);
  return 0;
}
```

I get following error:

```
  thr2.cpp:18:17: error: expected unqualified-id
  thread::thread<MyThread*>(MyThread*&&)
```

Do You have any ideas what might be the problem?
regards,
Mat

Comment: Specializing stuff in `std` except for a few cases is UB.

Comment: There's an interesting question in here aside from the `std` issue. clang doesn't allow specifying the constructor template argument, it requires `template<> thread::thread(MyThread*&&)` (without the `<MyThread*>`) instead. Is it correct in doing so?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? The `std::thread` constructor expects a callable type, and the implementation of the thread class relies on that. `MyThread*` is not a callable type, so there is no way this will work without some plumbing that relies on details of the implementation. In other words, this sounds like a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is not legal.  You can add speciaizations per [[namespace.constraints]\2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.constraints#namespace.std-2)

> Unless explicitly prohibited, a program may add a template specialization for any standard library class template to namespace std provided that (a) the added declaration depends on at least one user-defined type and (b) the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template.

But, [[namespace.constraints]\4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/namespace.constraints#namespace.std-4) goes on to state that

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it declares
>
> - an explicit specialization of any member function of a standard library class template,

So you cannot do this.